Light switch wiring help
The dimmer switch in our bathroom was replaced about a month ago.
Recently the breaker just started popping.
I'm not too sure if the wiring is right or what is going on.
Any information on what I should do ?
Please help.


why is the breaker popping?

@jsotola, I think that is her question.

Immediately after replacing the switch, or how long afterwards, did this issue occur. What is "popping"? GFCI or overload of the breaker? Does the issue still occur if one wire is removed from the dimmer and capped?

It was about a month to after he replaced the light switch then when we'd go to flip the light switch on it'd blow the breaker.

Needs improvement: formatting, punctuation, sentence structure etc.

Please show where the other wires are going

This looks like a 3-way switch with the wires connected to wrong terminals (one of which is ground?!?).


Turn the circuit breaker off.

Put the wires back in the box.

Call an electrician.



How would the OP know where the wires were in the past. Most don't know where they were immediately after removal.  This post gives no help.

@RMDman Edited for clarity.

makes a bit more sense now.
